# How to make Powershell autocomplete like Linux/Unix systems or "cmd" shell?

Tags: windows, powershell

## Situation

Every time that I hit TAB key the Powershell completes with an `.\` at the begging of the completed word.

---

### Example

I have one file named `Test.jar` and I will use `mv` command to change the name of the file to any other. If I press TAB while typing the existing file it's look like:

```
$ mv .\Test.jar ...
```

Have I way that I could change the autocompletion behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Some would argue that the PowerShell Autocomplete behavior is "more" correct, and "syntactically better" than bash or equivalent having a plain file name.

When it adds `.\` to the beginning, it doesn't affect functionality. It is *clarifying* what you are entering. It both *clarifies* that:

1. You are working with a **File Name** as opposed to a command i.e. If you have a file named "mv", you could see that it is a file that you are working with.
2. It is clarifies that the location of the file is located in the current working directory.

Comment: I agree, but some programs don't have support for this write (e.g., java 8). Because of that, I was wondering if I could switch between behaviors.